# St. Simeon the God-receiver and the Septuagint

Tags: jesus, judaism

St. Simeon the God-receiver was one of the seventy two scholars who came to Alexandria to translate the Holy Scriptures into Greek. God promised him that he would not die until the promised Messiah, Christ the Lord, came into the world. There are various traditions on how old he was. St. Jerome argues that only Pentateuch were translated in the late 3rd century BC and the rest including Simeon's translation of Isaiah might be written later in the late 1st century BC.

Ancient historians tell us that the Egyptian pharaoh *Ptolemy II Philadelphus (285-247 B.C.)* wished to include texts of Holy Scripture in the famous Library at Alexandria. He invited scholars from Jerusalem, and the Sanhedrin sent their wise men. The Righteous Simeon was one of the seventy scholars who came to Alexandria to translate the Holy Scriptures into Greek. The completed work was called “*The Septuagint*,” and is the version of the Old Testament used by the Orthodox Church.

Saint Simeon was translating a book of the Prophet Isaiah, and read the words: “**Behold, a virgin shall conceive in the womb, and shall bring forth a Son**” (Is 7:14). He thought that “virgin” was **inaccurate**, and he wanted to **correct** the text to read “woman.” **At that moment an angel appeared to him and held back his hand saying, “You shall see these words fulfilled. You shall not die until you behold Christ the Lord born of a pure and spotless Virgin.”**

From this day, Saint Simeon lived in expectation of the Promised Messiah. One day, the righteous Elder received a revelation from the Holy Spirit, and came to the Temple. It was on the very day (the fortieth after the Birth of Christ) when the All-Pure Virgin Mary and Saint Joseph had come to the Temple in order to perform the ritual prescribed by Jewish Law.

When Saint Simeon beheld their arrival, the Holy Spirit revealed to him that the divine Child held by the All-Pure Virgin Mary was the Promised Messiah, the Savior of the world. The Elder took the Child in his arms and said, “Lord, now lettest Thou Thy servant depart in peace, according to Thy word, for mine eyes have seen Thy salvation, which Thou hast prepared before the face of all people, a light to enlighten the Gentiles, and the glory of Thy people Israel” (Luke 2:29-32).

Therefore, my question is, according to this historical report of Simeon before the birth of Jesus rendering Isaiah as "young woman" rather than "virgin," and then being **corrected** by an **angel** that indeed it renders "virgin" and not "young woman" (referring to Mary and the birth of Jesus) how do you reconcile with this (as Jews or rejectors of this prophecy) **academically**?

Sources:

- [Holy, Righteous Simeon the God-Receiver](https://www.oca.org/saints/lives/2015/02/03/100409-holy-righteous-simeon-the-god-receiver)
- [The Ancient Versions on Isaiah 7.14](https://septuagintstudies.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/the-ancient-versions-on-isaiah-7-14/) by John Meade

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Windup.... Sadly I’m voting to close this question because it is mainly about Christian tradition, not the biblical text -- If it does get closed perhaps it can be migrated posted on the Christianity.se site.

Comment: There are many cases where the LXX changes the meaning of the Hebrew - Isa 7:14 is one of them - there are many more.

Comment: If my math is correct, this would make St Symeon nearly 300 years old at the time of Jesus' birth, since he would have to be an adult when he was invited Ptolemy II to translate the LXX. Rather unlikely IMO... even it the number is only 250.

Comment: The text is clearly a legend, and I am sure Isaiah was not translated so late, it is argued to avoid showing the man to have lived 3 centuries. This LXX scholars James Aitken gives a perfect explanation about the parthenos (virgin) translation, though it is accurate translation, but he says, it must have caused certain Christians to postulate virgin birth, leading to the deification of Mary and turning her into parthenon goddess diana etc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rl1Y7NijY1U

Answer (score 1):

This question is about to be closed because it primarily concerns a non-biblical text.  However, in the spirit of being helpful, I offer a few comments about the Biblical part of the question.

1. The operative word in Isa 7:14 is עַלְמָה (almah) which simply means young woman of marriageable age, whether virgin or not.  It occurs 7 times in the OT (Gen 24:43, Ex 2:8, Ps 68:25, Prov 30:19, SS 1:3, 6:8, Isa 7:14).  In none of these cases does the meaning demand that it be translated as "virgin" but is most helpfully translated, "maiden" or "young lady".
2. In the LXX, it is invariably translated as the equivalent of "maiden" or "young lady" in all places except Isa 7:14 where it is translated, παρθένος "virgin".  Just why the LXX translators chose "virgin", an interpretive translation, remains a mystery.  However, this is one of hundreds of places where the Masoretic text and the LXX depart from each other.
3. In Isa 7:14, the prophecy refers to Isaiah's wife, who was not a virgin because she had already had children and would have another as a sign concerning the fate of Assyria.
4. It is the evangelist, Matthew, writing under divine inspiration, who is inspired to re-purpose this prophecy as messianic in Matt 1:23, and uses the same LXX translation of παρθένος "virgin".  Other OT prophecies were re-purposed by NT writers, but that is well-beyond the scope here.

Further than this we cannot go.

Comment: Given the way young girls were guarded by father, brothers or other close relatives, to ensure they were virgins when they later married, the common-place word to describe such an unmarried girl or woman would be understood to include her being a virgin.   But a woman who had been raped, or had already borne children could only be understood by that word as a female (not necessarily young, either). This is what I have long understood, anyway. I know nothing about the tradition related by the OP but the NT is clear that Mary was, indeed a virgin when she miraculously conceived.

Comment: The NT is indeed clear on that point, but it raises another question: how was the historical Immanuel of Isaiah 7-8 conceived? Or was there no such person?